# What are the Dangers of using a Singleton in a multithreaded application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, singleton

I'm looking at using a singleton in a multithreaded  Win service for doing logging, and wanted to know what are some of the problems I might encounter. I have already set up the get instance to handle syncing with

```
    private static volatile Logging _instance;
    private static object _syncRoot = new object();

    private Logging(){}
    public static Logging Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance==null)
            {
                lock(_syncRoot)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                    {
                        _instance = new Logging();
                    }
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
```

Is there anything else I might need to worry about?

Comment: Here be dragons! Run while you can.

Comment: “Meddle not in the affairs of the dragon; for you are crunchy and taste good with ketchup.”

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That looks pretty good to me.

See [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) for more info.

Edit: Should probably put the return inside the lock, though.

Comment: and lock before comparing instance to null.

Comment: @Joel: No, this is deliberate double-checked locking. It's fiddly, but it does work - if you get it exactly right.

Comment: Bah, what's the point of me showing up to pimp my article if someone else has already linked to it? ;)

Comment: @Jon Holy cow. I've referenced that article for months and had no clue you wrote it.

Comment: The funny part is that in Jon's post, the link is broken :)

Answer (score 12):

This is more informational than anything else.

What you've posted is the *double-checked locking algorithm* - and what you've posted *will* work, as far as I'm aware. (As of Java 1.5 it works there, too.) However, it's very fragile - if you get any bit of it wrong, you could introduce very subtle race conditions.

I usually prefer to initialize the singleton in the static initializer:

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }

    private Singleton()
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

(Add a static constructor if you want a bit of extra laziness.)

That pattern's easier to get right, and in most cases it does just as well.

There's more detail on my [C# singleton implementation page](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) (also linked by Michael).

As for the dangers - I'd say the biggest problem is that you lose testability. Probably not *too* bad for logging.

Comment: the link to your article is broken.

Comment: That's pretty sad, isn't it? Such are the dangers of posting with a stinking cold. Fixed, thanks for noticing.

Comment: What's the reason of using property here? Isn't it safe enough to use public static readonly field?

Comment: @ArthurStankevich: If you make it a property, you can change the implementation later - e.g. to move to using a field in a nested class, if you want to be able to have static methods within `Singleton` which *don't* trigger initialization. (Admittedly at the moment they wouldn't guarantee to, but I'd probably use a static constructor here in reality anyway, which changes the timing.) Basically, I've found that using a property gives you more flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

Singleton's have the potential to become a bottleneck for access to the resource embodied by the class, and force sequential access to a resource that could otherwise be used in parallel.

In this case, that may not be a bad thing, because you don't want multiple items writing to your file at the same instant, and even so I don't think your implementation will have that result.  But it's something to be aware of.

Comment: I would rather it bottleneck then crash, which is what was happening when I had to much activity that's the reason I am looking at using a singleton. +1 for good insight

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that each method in the logger are safe to run concurrently, i.e. that they don't write to shared state without proper locking.

Comment: Doesn't using a singleton prevent you from running them concurrently? I thought that was the point.

Comment: No, multiple threads can still access the single Logging instance. Its methods *need* to be thread-safe. +1 for bringing this up.

Comment: @bob: your double-check locking prevents more than one instance from being created (to guarantee singleton-ness), it does not prevent concurrent access from multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

You are using [double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_checked_locking_pattern) what is considered a anti-pattern. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) has patterns with and without lazy initialization for different languages.

After creating the singleton instance you must of course ensure that all methods are thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

A better suggestion would be to establish the logger in a single-threaded setup step, so it's guaranteed to be there when you need it.  In a Windows Service, OnStart is a great place to do this.

Another option you have is to used the System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(T%, T, T) : T method to switch out.  It's less confusing and it's guaranteed to work.

```
System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange<Logging>(_instance, null, new Logging());
```

Comment: I'm not a C# expert but I would expect this to generate a new Logging instance on every call. The `new Logging()` part is executed before the atomic check inside of InterlockedCompareExchange.

Comment: You're right.  How bad that would be really depends on the semantics of the Logging constructor (and initializers). I hold that it still works, and the first suggestion is better.

Answer (score 1):

There is some debate with respect to the need to make the first check for null use Thread.VolatileRead() if you use the double checked locking pattern and want it to work on all memory models.  An example of the debate can be read at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/b1932d46-877f-41f1-bb9d-b4992f29cedc/.

That said,  I typically use Jon Skeet's solution from above.

Answer (score 0):

I think if Logging instance methods are thread-safe there's nothing to worry about.